# Work of intersection of surfaces

Tags: integration

> Calculate the work of the vectorial field $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that $f(x,y,z)=(x,z,2y)$ in the curve given by the intersection of two surfaces: $x^2 + y^2 = 1 $ and $ z = x^2 - y^2 $ in the anti-clock direction senn by the point (0,0,100)

My attempt:

I tried to parametrize both my equations making $x = \rho \cos \phi $ and $y = \rho \sin \phi $

I got to $\rho = 1$ and $ z = \cos (2\phi)$

So I have my curve

$g (\phi) = (\cos \phi, \sin \phi, cos 2\phi) $

With $0<\phi<2\pi$ because of the anti-clock thing.

Anyway however I don't know what to do next and how does the point given will affect the resolution. I'm a bit confused on how to proceed next. Can someone clarify me a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Your parametrization is good. The work done is the line integral
$$
\int_{g} F \cdot ds
  = \int_{0}^{2\pi} F\bigl(g(\phi)\bigr) \cdot g'(\phi)\, d\phi.
$$